# How i can bind an actionlistener with js or jquery using timpickiv2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

realized that it is time to Register in stackoferflow. My Problem:

I am doing a side with html, css and JavaScript/Jquery. The side is a timesheet and is looking right now like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfQH7.png).

The shown timepicker is timepickiv2. I'm happy with it, but after trying to add Actionlisteners i realized, that it should work different as i am trying.

Reading the documentary of timepicki i found this. Please help me to bind a actionlistener which read the field start, end, and pause after changing any of them and compute the hours worked. Every field got their own id: ( as example)

field timepicker at start of the 21.04.2017 has the id 21042017start, ende has the id 21042017ende.

I thought about something like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".timepicki-input").change(function (e) {
                var id = $(this).id.substring(0, 7);
                var start = $('#' + id + 'start');
                var ende = $('#' + id + 'ende');
                $('#' + id + 'bruStd').text('bla');
            });
        });
```

This i found on timpicki js data:

```
                // 2) For any other key presses:
            //      i) realize that we cannot check what the user has typed
            //         just yet, because this function is a handler
            //         that runs before any text is rendered in the input
            //         box.
            //      ii) So, register a function validate() that will execute right 
            //          after the keypress character is rendered. All validation
            //          is done inside validate().
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            //  NOTE:.change() event does not work here, as it is called when input looses focus|
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're defining the `computeHours()` function, but never calling it. Therefore, the code it contains is never executed. The `.change()` listener never gets bound.

Comment: yes! i edited it but it still does not work. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's hard to say, as "it doesn't work" doesn't provide anything to work with. It's like you say to your mechanic, "My car doesn't work, what's the fix?" I have no idea, because I don't know what's "not working", I don't know if you get an error in your console or anything. `$(this).id` is probably undefined, what does your console say?